Name of 60s/70s Hammer(?) Film
When I was a wee lass of 6, my parents dragged me to their friends house for a dinner party and made me hang out with their son.  His parents told us to watch a movie, and tuned the TV to "Creature Double Feature."
As I recall, the plot of the film had something to do with a couple(?) (engaged? newlyweds?) spending time in somebody's (mansion-like?) ancestral home.  The only scene I recall involved one person handing the other a goblet and saying words to the effect, "Drink this (blood?) and become a member of the family Whatever."  The second person does something with the goblet (drinks or not, I can't recall), looks up and sees that the first person has become a skeleton.
I'd never been so scared in my short life.
(Come on, I was six! And it was the 70s!)
Through the years I've tried to find the movie again, with no success.  It may have been a Hammer film. Any leads from the admittedly very vague clues much appreciated!

Here's a Hammer filmography list, could it be one of those? It is a long list, Hammer productions have been around since the mid-30's, but the listing is separated by decade.
